# How to solve the Identical URL Pattern Conflict in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

while practicing on Django I have faced the following problem of Identical URL Pattern. I have tried but fail to solve.

My project has one apps and the models are

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,blank=True, max_length=255)

class Post(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   cats = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,blank=True, max_length=255)
```

My urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from post import views as apps

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('<slug:slug>/', apps.categoryView, name='category'),
    path('<slug:slug>/',apps.PostView, name='calc_detail'),
]
```

**Problem:**

When I Put '/' in the second line of the urlpattern for Category View, category View works but post View doesn't work (404).

If remove '/' urlpattern for CategoryView , then post view Works but Category Views shows 404.

How should I configure these urls. I am using function based views

Answer (score 0):

There's really no way to handle these except using different patterns or handling both in the same view, I would suggest different patterns:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from post import views as apps

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('pattern1/<slug:slug>/', apps.categoryView, name='category'),
    path('pattern2/<slug:slug>/',apps.PostView, name='calc_detail'),
]
```

Also have you thought what would happen if a post and a category ended up having the same slug? Best to have different patterns.
About putting '/' making some url work and not it is because django appends slashes by default to each url, so if you really want to do this **(NOT RECOMMENDED)** you may set `APPEND_SLASH = False` in your setting and have one url with a slash and other without.

Comment: if I do make the slug field as CharField for category and set the url pattern like this

path('<str:url>/', apps.categoryView, name='category'),

will it work ??

Comment: thank you. Then how i generate static pages like 'about' or others

Comment: You write a view for them, and a url pattern.

Comment: I have tried with simple url pattern

path('about',apps.aboutView, name='about'),

it works with appending without '/' . if  I put  '/' at the end it shows 404. :(  I  am confused now

Comment: I was put the static pages at the last line of the url pattern. At that time it doesn't work. After putting it in the third line rigth after the home page, it works. Thanks a lot buddy